# How to paint the page while javascript calculates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have a page where we perform totals and other calculations on user-inputted data. It works on the *keyup* event.

The problem: that data is never stored, merely calculated, so when we load a page with existing data the formulae never get calculated until the user presses a button in that field.

Our solution works but is incredibly slow: we trigger a *keyup* event for every field that can take user input. The problem is that the page locks up for 20 seconds... We tried making the function that triggers a *keyup* event for every cell asynchronous (*async* keyword) in addition to all the functions that handle the recalculation but that hasn't helped.

What are we missing so that the recalculation works in the background without locking out the user? We didn't install any special library to do the async work.

Comment: If you're loading the data from the server why not pre-calculate the calculated fields on the server and then insert that data into the view too? Then it would be already there when the page loads. The only downside is you have to re-implement the same logic in server side code

Comment: Also why are you triggering lots of keyup events? That should not be necessary. Separate the calculation functionality into functions which can be called independently without needing the keyup. Then you can call them directly when the page loads, which should be more efficient than triggering lots of events I think. That's an alternative if you don't like the server side idea

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: will u share a code snippet ? at least we can identify the issue.

Comment: You could try [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for you calculation. Then your javascript code doesn't block other code execution. For better answers you should include some code.